# Unfolding tensor containing image into patches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a batch of size `4` of size `h x w = 180 x 320` single channel images. I want to unfold them series of `p` smaller patches of shape `h_p x w_p` yielding tensor of shape `4 x p x h_p x w_p`. If `h` is not divisible for `h_p`, or `w` is not divisible for `w_p`, the frames will be 0-padded. I tried following to achieve this:

```
import torch
tensor = torch.randn(4, 180, 320)
patch_size = (64, 64) #h_p = w_p = 64
unfold = torch.nn.Unfold(kernel_size=patch_size, stride=patch_size, padding=0)
unfolded = unfold(tensor)
print(unfolded.shape)
```

It prints:

```
torch.Size([16384, 10])
```

What I am missing here?

**PS:**

I guess I have found the solution myself which I have posted below. I am yet to evaluate it fully. But let me know if you find it wrong or poor in any sense, may be performance

Answer (score 1):

I had input of shape `[#batches, height, width] = [4,180,320]`.  I wanted to unfold them in sequence of `p` smaller patches of shape `h_p x w_p` yielding tensor of shape `4 x p x h_p x w_p`. Notice that to cover all `h x w = 180 x 320` elements using patch of size `h_p x w_p = 64 x 64`, I will need `p = 3 x 5 = 15` patches:
[image]

So, I added padding of 6 rows on both sides, top and bottom. Rest of the code I have explained in comments:

```
patch_size = (64,64)
input = torch.randn(4,180,320)

# Padding 6 rows on top and bottom, to make up total padding of 12 rows, 
# so that our frame will become of size 192 x 320 and we can fit 3
# kernels of size 64 x 64 vertically
input = f.pad(input, pad=(0,0,6,6))
print(input.shape) # [4,192,320]

# add additional dimension indicating single channel
input = input.unsqueeze(1) # [4,1,192, 320]
print(input.shape)

# unfold with both stride and kernel size of 64 x 64
unfold = torch.nn.Unfold(kernel_size=patch_size, stride=(64,64))
unfolded = unfold(input)
print(unfolded.shape) # [4, 4096, 15] 
# 4 for batch size
# 4096 = 64 x 64 elements in one patch
# 15 = we can fit 15 patches of size 64 x 64 in frame of size 192 x 329

# reshape result to desired size
# size(0) = 4 = batch size
# -1 to infer p or number of patches, by our calculations it will be 15
# *patch_size = 64 x 64
unfolded = unfolded.view(unfolded.size(0),-1,*patch_size) 
print(unfolded.shape) # [4, 15, 64, 64]
```

This correctly output:

```
torch.Size([4, 192, 320])
torch.Size([4, 1, 192, 320])
torch.Size([4, 4096, 15])
torch.Size([4, 15, 64, 64]
```